# Replace split with explode in all PHP files

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression, php, xargs

How can I replace the obsolete `split` PHP command with `explode` in a folder structure with many files?

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I figured it out myself.

```
find . -iname '*.php' -type f -exec grep -l -m 1 -P '[<][?]' {} \; | xargs -r grep -l -m 1 --null -P '[^_.]split[\s]*[(]' | sudo xargs -0 -r perl -pi -e 's/([^_.])split([\s]*[(])/$1explode$2/g'
```

1. Get PHP files (case-insensitive).
2. Check if `<?` is inside.
3. Check if `split(` is inside.
4. Replace `split(` with `explode(`.

For 3 and 4: `_split(` (`preg_split`) and `.split(` (Javascript in my case) won't be replaced.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Refactoring code is generally best left to IDEs

Comment: I upvoted your comment. But finally understanding all this find, grep, xargs, sed/perl, pipe and regex stuff makes me happy. :) It was a long run. :)